# Move data between partition

Tags: partition, data

I have a slow drive with a big chunk of data that I want to cut/paste in an other partition (of the same drive obviously, otherwise I shouldn't speak about partition but drives directly), but this chunk is so big that I can't just copy then delete it (so the buffer should be the RAM, not the drive itself)

> the target one is currently too small to handle the file in its entirety.

Is there even a solution for that? Or should I get an other drive to make a "buffer"? Because it will be so slow and long to do like that

The source is in an NTFS partition and destination a EXT4

Comment: What happens when you try `cp`? Do you get any error?

Comment: I didn't even tried before knowing because I don't want data loss, and the CP will surely fail because I don't have the space to make a copy, I need the space and the data of the NTFS partition to goes into the EXT4 one

Comment: Hang on... you want to use the _same disk space_ first for your valuable data that's on an NTFS partition, and then secondly for a new EXT4 partition? That's really asking for trouble. Either your data is valuable, in which borrow or buy a spare disk to which you can copy the data temporarily, or it isn't (valuable), in which case just throw it away.

Comment: Okay so it's not possible
I guess I will just redownload all from internet then, no need to bother with transferring, although it will be very long

Comment: It's _possible_ to copy data from one partition to the other, then resize the two partitions and their filesystems to move the disk space from the old to new partitions, repeating as necessary to get all of the data moved. It would probably be faster than downloading it all again from the Internet, but is error-prone. Not that the drive should lose the data, but that you as the human can goof up.

Comment: I have a 2 GB NTFS and 1 GB EXT4, the drive is 3 GB sized and I have a file on the NTFS who is 1.5 GB large, you tell me that theres a way to copy it to the EXT4 partition ?

Comment: How much physical memory (RAM) do you have in your system?

Comment: You should [edit] the question and clearly state the partitions are on the same device and the target one is currently too small to handle the file in its entirety. The question in its current form is unclear. Only after I read your first comment I learnt what the real problem is.

Comment: Have you tried to `gzip` the files? And maybe try your `-9 --best`. Unless if size doesn't get smaller (e.g. media files), it could be less than 1GB, and you move them, then you can change the NTFS partition to ext4, extract the files there, then modify the remaining partition to NTFS. You will have at the end again 2 partitions (I guess you need them) and the files at the ext4 which will be the larger one.

Comment: @roaima we consider here that the RAM is not the bottleneck but that you need the space of the old partition to move the file, so in state it seems to be impossible

Comment: @thanasisp the 3GB example was a summarized problem to make light on the real problem that I talk about, real files are about 200GB large (so compression should be slower than re-download and move added together)